# How to Get Fully Functional PowerShell running on Linux?

Tags: linux, powershell

Getting powershell running on Linux is straightforward. 
Unfortunately this is based on .NetCore which excludes a lot a important functionality and modules e.g the DNSServer module.
Is there a workaround to obtain a fully functional PowerShell installation on linux including modules that don't appear in .NetCore (specifically DNSServer) ?

Comment: Please ask to the developers at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules like DNSServer are owned and maintained by the DNS team within Microsoft and aren't part of the PowerShell project itself. This also means they aren't open source.

On top of that, for DNSServer specifically, that module uses WMI under the hood (I'd go so far as to say it's a thin wrapper around the WMI calls), and since WMI is also not open source and not available on Linux I'd say there's little chance of this module making there any time soon.

As a general case, your best bet is probably to use PSRemoting from Linux to a Windows machine that has the modules you want, then either use Implicit Remoting (`Import-PSSession`) or just straight up make remote calls with `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: I know there is "wmic" which provides wmi on Linux. I imagine this might make it possible to get modules like this running on linux and communicating via WMI.

Comment: @TraianoWelcome these modules don't shell out though, they use internal dot net classes for it which aren't included in core, so it would probably be a rewrite and make them (even more) unreliable. Remoting is probably the best way, but you could try to roll your own module that wraps `wmic` if you have a version that runs on linux.